# Web View in React Native not getting rendered

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a web view component that is not getting rendered. The webview is from react-native-webview. Here's my webview component:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<Text>hello</Text>
          <WebView 
              source={{
                  uri: 'https://www.google.com'
              }}
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
          />
<Text>hello</Text>
      </View>
```

Both the hellos are rendered, but the webview isn't. Also the place where the webview component is getting rendered, other components are also there but with display:none.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had tried your code it's working perfectly:

check this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text} from 'react-native'
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
class App extends React.Component {
render(){
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>hello</Text>
                  <WebView 
                      source={{
                          uri: 'https://www.google.com'
                      }}
                      style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  />
        <Text>hello</Text>
              </View>
            );
}

};

export default App;
```

[image]

Hope this helps!